# Strange behavior of unicode text

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Basically I have this code:

```
page = requests.get("some_url" )

tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

fo = codecs.open("path to file", "w", encoding='utf8')

txt = tree.xpath("some_xpath_expr")

fo.write( txt )

fo.close()
```

and it saves the xpath to the file. But when I do:

`txt = page.content` instead of `txt=tree.xpath()`
 ,when I write to the file, it returns

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0
```

So, if I do:

`txt = page.content.encode("utf8")`

it works fine again.

So, my question is why this happens? I mean does the `tree.xpath` return unicode string and the `requests.get()` doesn't? I am confused.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand your question, but are you saying that when you execute the 2 lines `page = requests.get("some_url" )` and then immediately after that `txt = page.content`, you see the `UnicodeDecodeError`? That can't be right: all you have done is bound `page.content` to another variable `txt`. No character encoding/decoding should be taking place there.

Comment: @mhawke Yes, the question was misleading, I edited it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`page.content` gives you the binary/bytes response content, not the textual response content. You probably want to use `page.text` instead of `page.content`. When something expects text and you give it bytes, python will usually try to convert the bytes to text with the ascii codec, which ni your case is failing because the content is not ascii-encoded (it's probably utf-8). You can check what response encoding was used by looking at `page.encoding`, but if you use `page.text` directly then you don't need to care what encoding was used.

Refs:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content